# Can't remove version tag even having dependencyManagement in pom.xml

Tags: maven, spring-cloud

I'm trying to create a discovery microservice with spring cloud. I'm adding `spring-cloud-dependencies-parent` as pom to manage dependencies, but it seems I cannot remove `version` tag from other dependencies. Here's this part of `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
<!--            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I can just uncomment `version` tags and everything will compile fine, but it seems I have a version mismatch here and I'd prefer versions to be handled automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`spring-cloud-dependencies-parent` is a parent pom with 0 dependency management. Probably just a typo? Try

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Hoxton.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

> Hint: you can go to https://start.spring.io/#!dependencies=cloud-starter and click on "Explore" to get the same information.